# Flask render_template() does not render the xhtml, but it renders correctly in my browser when I open it manually

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, jinja2, xhtml

I am trying to render xhtml (X3D) files. The Problem is that when rendering those through a flask route one xhtml template would work correctly and another one not. Both files work perfectly fine when I open them in my browser manually. The secound file is a modification of the first one using BeautifulSoup.

```
#flask app module
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/xhtml')
def xhtml():
    return render_template('8b0e87efd5144053916a1cadfc9c5194.xhtml')

@app.route('/xhtml_2')
def xhtml_2():
    return render_template('920e053d8e474fc1869e9a2c763e9186.xhtml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Is there something that I am missing about render_template()?

Working file: https://pastebin.com/qQi96Fcq

NOT working file: https://pastebin.com/HJiD9WTZ

[image: Screenshot of how both files are rendered]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both files are very similar, because the secound file is just a modification of the first file using BeatifulSoup. I played around with the files and changed codeblocks step by step. I figured out, that BeautifulSoup changed

```
<Viewpoint ... ></Viewpoint>
```

to

```
<Viewpoint ... />
```

and jinja does not seem to like it. After changing those tags in the broken file it now gets rendered correctly:

```
<Viewpoint ... > </Viewpoint>
```

Even though noone could solve that Problem for me, I am still thankful for your input, as it got me thinking about my Problem more focussed.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there something that I am missing about render_template()?*

According to [Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/templates/)

> Flask uses the Jinja template library to render templates.

Is not that *one xhtml template would work correctly* by coincidence valid `Jinja` template?

Comment: Both files are just "plain" html code without any jinja syntax. I am not sure that this is the problem. Nevertheless I will look into that. I am already comparing both files, but I cannot spot any difference that I would expect to cause that problem.

Comment: I have attached both files.

Answer (score 0):

`jinja` by default expects `.html` as extension for templates, but for your case you want to render template with an other extension `.xhtml`, to do so you need to **autoescape** that custom extension and you have to enable it globally in your `Flask` app like so

```
from jinja2 import select_autoescape

app.jinja_env.autoescape = select_autoescape(      
    default_for_string=True,    
    enabled_extensions=('html', 'xhtml')
)
```

refer to https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/

let me know if it was useful.

Comment: but both files are xhtml, and one of them does get rendered and the other one doesnt.

Comment: I added the autoescape but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change "content-type" from "text/html" to "application/xhtml+xml". HTML does not accept self-closing tags. XHTML, however, does.

"However, even if the document properly validates as XHTML, what really determines XHTML/HTML processing in browsers is the MIME type, which as said before is often not set properly. So the valid XHTML was being treated as invalid HTML."

Source: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/htmlfaq/

Changed code parts:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response

@app.route('/xhtml_2')
def xhtml_2():
    resp = make_response(render_template('920e053d8e474fc1869e9a2c763e9186.xhtml'), 200)
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xhtml+xml'
    return resp
```